# Send authentication headers with Node http post request

Tags: node.js

I have made a http client using Node that sends a post request. However the service has  NTLM authentication enabled. How do I add my username and password in the post request ?

```
var http=require('http')
var options = {
    host: 'kmserver28',
    port: 3535,
    path: '/Alto/Post/PostFetchWS.asmx/FetchPosts',
    method: 'POST'
};

var req = http.request(options, function(res){
    console.log('status: ' + res.statusCode);
    console.log('headers: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    res.on('data', function(chunk){
        console.log("body: " + chunk);
    });
});

req.on('error', function(e) {
    console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
});

// write data to request body
req.write('data\n');
req.write('data\n');
req.end();
```

Answer (score 1):

Came across this while trying to get basic authorization working.  I was able to get it working by adding an authorization header in the options object.  Mine was for basic, but NTLM should be similar, I believe:

```
var api_options = {
host: process.env.API_HOST,
path: process.env.API_PATH,
method: 'POST',
headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(body),
    'Authorization': 'Basic ' + new Buffer(process.env.API_USERNAME + ':' + process.env.API_PASSWORD).toString('base64')
}
```